# Pandas: create column id based on intersections on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

| id1 | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | u |
| a | y | j |
| b | x | t |
| c | z | r |
| d | p | r |

and I need to create a new column ID taking into consideration all the intersections between values in columns id1, id2 and id3.

The output required is as follows:

| id1 | id2 | id3 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | u | 1 |
| a | y | j | 1 |
| b | x | t | 1 |
| c | z | r | 2 |
| d | p | r | 2 |

with

- ID=1 considering id1: [a,b], id2: [x,y], id3: [u,j,t]
- ID=2 considering id1: [c,d], id2: [z,p], id3: [r]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot for possible pass 2 columns to [`convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) and get all [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html) for dicionary, last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars='id1', value_vars=['id2','id3'])

import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1,'id1','value')

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1

df['g'] = df['id1'].map(node2id)
print (df)
  id1 id2 id3  g
0   a   x   u  1
1   a   y   j  1
2   b   x   t  1
3   c   z   r  2
4   d   p   r  2
```